# Time interval formatter?

Tags: cocoa, ios, nsdateformatter

We all know and love the [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDateFormatter).

Is there anything similar to format time intervals, like the number of seconds, minutes, hours, days, or months between two dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the three20 framework by facebook - it has some tools for doing that

Comment: This looks like a very useful library, and I will definitely check it out! For who wants to use this as well, features and code sniplets can be found <a href="http://three20.info/article/2010-10-07-Three20-Tidbits">here</a>.

Comment: Please offer a link to the library [and some example code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) of how it might be used and what the expected result might be